# is it possible to create groups of contacts with Converse.js

Tags: xmpp, converse.js

I'd like to customize the user interface of Converse.js . The goal is to create groups of contacts.
For example:

- Group A1 : John Doe, Alice DY
- Group B1 : Lucy MA, John Doe, Jack KA

Is it possible ? Is there a plugin ?

Converse.js version: v7.0.4.

Thanks;

Comment: Converse already supports grouping of contacts. With the latest version, when you add a contact, you can choose the group(s).

Comment: thanks @JCBrand
what is the oldest version of Converse.js supporting grouping of contacts ?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to add a contact with group info, there is already a button on the main view of converse.js
[image]

Otherwise, if you want to add contacts in a batch to an existing group, you can implement a plugin.

BTW, I'm using the latest version 10.1.0 to implement plugins.